# where do I find the bitizins when I accepted them from my friends?

Tags: tiny-tower

I received two bitizins from a friend, I pressed keep but after that they are nowhere to be found. Any ideas why ?

Answer (score 1):

They should be in the lobby, and you just put them on a residential floor like you would with VIP's. Hope I helped!